# bigquery split not returning the right answer

Tags: split, google-bigquery

I have a dataset of one column (named "path")

Two example records are :

/shop/category/misc/product-one-a3-midnight-black/?sid=spl12345
/shop/category/misc/product-one-a3-midnight-black/

```
NTH(1,split(path, '/')) one,
NTH(2,split(path, '/')) two,
NTH(3,split(path, '/')) three,
NTH(4,split(path, '/')) four
```

one always returns "shop"
two always returns "category"
three always returns "misc"
but four returns "?sid=spl12345" for record 1 and "product-one-a3-midnight-black" for record two. I except both records to return "product-one-a3-midnight-black" since they both come after the fourth "/"

When i type it out manually i.e.

```
SELECT  NTH(1,split(path, '/')) one,
              NTH(2,split(path, '/')) two,
              NTH(3,split(path, '/')) three,
              NTH(4,split(path, '/')) four from
        (SELECT "/shop/category/misc/product-one-a3-midnight-black/?sid=spl12345" AS path),
         (SELECT "/shop/category/misc/product-one-a3-midnight-black/" AS path),
```

It seems to work. But for some reason using my big table in bigquery doesn't work - does anyone know why?

Comment: What happens if you REPLACE(path, '/', ':') and split afterwards?

Comment: Hey shecode! did you have a second to try the query Felipe suggested? I'm curious as to the result on your table. If it doesn't help, can you copy exactly the two records that aren't returned properly and edit them in your question?

Comment: hi patrice, I ended up just using a regex as it was rather bazaar. I'll try Felipes suggestion sometime